# Why does this java test read false instead of true?

Tags: java, testing, assert

In java I have a test here are few lines of code from it:

```
StrategySlide strategySlide = mock(StrategySlide.class);
assertTrue(strategySlide.canSlide(board, fromCoords, toCoords));
```

This is a part of the canSlide code (i just put return true at the top to make sure it would always return true):

```
abstract public class StrategySlide implements StrategyFactoryI {

    public boolean canSlide(Board board, Coordinates from, Coordinates to) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

However upon running only this test I get the following output:

```
expected: <true> but was: <false>
Expected :true
Actual   :false
```

I have no idea why it would read false when I just do return true. Does anyone have a idea how this could happen?

Comment: What is `strategySlide`? How is it defined/assigned?

Comment: It sounds like `strategySlide` has its `canSlide` overridden.

Comment: Please [edit] the post and add a [MRE]. Otherwise, we are unable to help.

Comment: You could try to debug the test by putting a breakpoint on the `assertTrue(strategySlide.canSlide(...` line. Many IDEs allow that...

Comment: Why are you mocking strategySlide? If you want to **test** `StrategySlide`, then you should create an actual instance of it, not mock it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're mocking `strategySlide` and Mockito by default returns `false` for mocked methods that return a `boolean`.

From [the documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing):

> By default, for **all methods that return a value, a mock will return** either null, a primitive/primitive wrapper value, or an empty collection, as appropriate. For example 0 for an int/Integer and **false for a boolean/Boolean**.

If you want to test the actual implementation, then you shouldn't mock `StrategySlide` but create a new instance through the normal ways (eg. `new StrategySlide()`).

If you want to use Mockito to return a different value, you can use:

```java
when(strategySlide.canSlide(any(), any(), any()).thenReturn(true);
```

<sub>*(`when()` comes from `Mockito.when()` and `any()` comes from `ArgumentMatchers.any()`)*</sub>

Comment: @StackUser what was your expectation when using a mock?